# Handle dataGridView FormatExeption on edit

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm making a datagridview with four columns. The last column's type is DateTime in Hours and minutes (HH:mm).

```
    DataTable.Columns.Add("Time", typeof(DateTime)); //fourth column
    dataGridView2.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "HH:mm";
```

When i put in a valid HH:mm(12:37) format it works just fine, but it gives me an error message if the format is invalid (12:374).

```
    The string wasn't regigniced as a valid DateTime --> System.FormatExeption
```

It tells me to handle the "DataError-exeption / FormatExeption" to change what happens when the error occurs, but how do i do that?

I want it to go back to the value it was before the error occurs.

Any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance.

PS. If i'm unclear somewhere, or if you need more information then just explain what's needed.

EDIT: I am editing the time value directly from the dataGridView.

Comment: How you set data to Gridview?

Comment: What do you mean? Like dataGridView2.DataSource = DataTable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handle the event **[`DataGridView.DataError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.ondataerror.aspx)** so that you can proper manage the situation and show the correct messages to the user.

This example of event-handler below is taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.dataerror.aspx):

```
private void dataGridView2_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs     anError)
{

    MessageBox.Show("Error happened " + anError.Context.ToString());

    if (anError.Context == DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Commit error");
    }
    if (anError.Context == DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.CurrentCellChange)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cell change");
    }
    if (anError.Context == DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Parsing)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("parsing error");
    }
    if (anError.Context == DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.LeaveControl)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("leave control error");
    }

    if ((anError.Exception) is ConstraintException)
    {
        DataGridView view = (DataGridView)sender;
        view.Rows[anError.RowIndex].ErrorText = "an error";
        view.Rows[anError.RowIndex].Cells[anError.ColumnIndex].ErrorText = "an error";

        anError.ThrowException = false;
    }
}
```

And add it to your `DataGridView` instance:

```
dataGridView2.DataError += dataGridView2_DataError;
```

You can get more information about the event and input parameters expected from [this resource](http://www.visualbasicplanet.info/data-binding/datagridview-dataerror-event.html).

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnDataError(bool, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs)' is inaccessible due to its protection level
What does this mean?

Comment: Edited: `dataGridView2.DataError += dataGridView2_DataError;`

Answer (score 0):

in CellValidating event, you can set e.Cancel = true if there was an error. see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating.aspx

Comment: I am editing directly in the datagridview. The second i press enter to end the cell edit, it gives me the error message. Where would you then place this piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

Wire up a formatting event:

```
dataGridView.CellFormatting += new DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(dataGridView_CellFormat);

private void dataGridView_CellFormat(Object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("Time"))
    {
       DateTime dt;
       if (!DateTime.TryParse(e.Value.ToString(), out dt))
       {
           e.Value = "PreviousValue";
       }
    }
}
```

I don't know off-hand how to get the row's previous value, but this would be the idea.

Comment: Is this supposed to activate every second? even if the form with the code isn't open? The error still appears anyways when i edit the cell

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is i dont think its possible. Ive just had exactly the same problem only with a different data type. I event tried to edit the value before the data error event fired. From what i can gather the official way of handling this is to draw the users attention back the cell and correct the mistake. There are error text and error icons to help with this.

The new content of the cell is available through the formattedvalue property of the cell but this is read only and therefore cant be edited.

I would refer to the previous answer and work on trapping the error type to display a meaningful error message to the user

I ended up with the following few lines of code

```
Private Sub dgvInvoices_CellValidating(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles dgvInvoices.CellValidating
    dgvInvoices.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).ErrorText = ""
    Dim newInteger As Integer

    dgvInvoices.ShowCellErrors = True

    If Not Double.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), newInteger) OrElse newInteger < 0 Then

        e.Cancel = True
        dgvInvoices.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).ErrorText = "the value must be a non-negative integer"
        MsgBox("Ensure the value is a numeric value.", vbExclamation, "Error")

    End If

End Sub
```

Sorry i could help more

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19582852/c-sharp-formatexception-in-datagridview/31147974#31147974) - handle DataGridView.CellValidating event:

```
    private void CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {   
            // get current cell
            var cell = ((DataGridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
            // check new value. i need any number >= 5
            var c0 = 0;
            if (e.FormattedValue == null || !Int32.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), out c0) || c0 < 5)
            {
                // bad value inserted

                // e.FormattedValue - is new value
                // cell.Value - contains 'old' value

                // choose any:
                cell.Value = cell.Value;    // this way we return 'old' value
                e.Cancel = true;            // this way we make user not leave the cell until he pastes the value we expect
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The restore of previous value as shown doesn't work as it is

This is the right way to do it

```
((DataGridView)sender).EditingControl.Text = cell.Value.ToString();
```