# C# FormatException in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, formatexception

I created a DataGridView with some columns. The order columns only allow users enter int number. It throws the FormatException when I enter "j" (for example) and I try to add try catch to fix the problem, but it looks does not work..

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try{
     this.sourceTable = new DataTable(TableName);
     this.sourceTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(OrderCol, Type.GetType("System.Int32")));

     dataGridView1.DataSource = sourceTable;
  }catch(FormatException){
     MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number");
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but you could try to add **TypeLoadException** in addition to(or instead of) existing **FormatException**.

Comment: This try-cache only works while the form is loading. Later this won't have any effect. Maybe you could check the input with a DataColumnChangeEventHandler?

Comment: It would be great if you could comment if my answer below answers your question or if there are any questions left. If it's what you're searching for, it would be great if you could "accept" the answer, so other users with the same problem can see what helped you.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:
I've added an event for column changing where I can check the input when it's submitted.

```
private DataColumn dataColumn;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                this.sourceTable = new DataTable(TableName);
                dataColumn = new DataColumn(OrderCol);
                this.sourceTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn);
                sourceTable.ColumnChanged += sourceTable_ColumnChanged; // Eventhandler for column changes

                dataGridView1.DataSource = sourceTable;

        }

        void sourceTable_ColumnChanged(object sender, DataColumnChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int i = Convert.ToInt32(e.ProposedValue);

            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Handle DataGridView.CellValidating event:

```
    private void CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // get current cell
            var cell = ((DataGridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
            // check new value. i need any number >= 5
            var c0 = 0;
            if (e.FormattedValue == null || !Int32.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), out c0) || c0 < 5)
            {
                // bad value inserted

                // e.FormattedValue - is new value
                // cell.Value - contains 'old' value

                // choose any:
                cell.Value = cell.Value;    // this way we return 'old' value
                e.Cancel = true;            // this way we make user not leave the cell until he pastes the value we expect
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```