# Unable to Handle Default Error Dialog for Dynamic DataGridView (Multiple NULL values)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, dbnull

**WORK BRIEF:**

I have populated a `DataGridView` on `button_click` event. (Based on SQL query entered in the textbox, the `DataGridView` will be populated)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string strSQLQuery = textBox1.Text.Trim();

        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQLQuery, strCon);
        SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);
        dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        bool flag = false;
        if (!dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].IsNewRow)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells)
            {
                if (cell.Value == System.DBNull.Value)
                    flag = true;
            }
        }
        if(flag)
             MessageBox.Show("Many cells are empty");
}
```

**ISSUE:**

This works perfectly if none of the columns in the rows contain `NULL` values.
But if one or more `NULL` values found in any of the cells of the rows, I get the message box `"Many cells are empty"` as in my code. When I try moving horizontal scrollbar(I use to display more columns), I get the following `DataGridView` Default Error Dialog.

[image]

**TRIED SOLUTIONS:**

I have tried the following solutions. But none worked to solve this issue. Please do consider helping to solve this issue.

[LINK 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewdataerroreventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - MSDN - `DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs` Class

[LINK 2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dd2bf30d-bcf4-4786-a50e-bf334360cff2/how-to-check-datagridvew-cell-null-value-in-c?forum=csharplanguage) - Social MSDN Site

[LINK 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844624/handle-datagridview-formatexeption-on-edit) - Verified Answer in `StackOverflow`

[LINK 4](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24154225/How-do-I-catch-a-Datagridview-format-exception-and-set-cell-to-DBNull-value.html) - All Suggested and verified answer in `Experts-Exchange`

I also tried to avoid this error popping up by using the following method. But this doesn't seem to solve the issue.

```
private void dataGridView1_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

**PRELIMINARY INFO**

- *IDE:* Visual Studio 2010 Professional
- *.Net:* Version 4.0
- *Language Used:* C#
- *Database:* SQL Server 2008

Comment: The message indicates nothing wrong with the query but with drawing some image. Post more code. What are you doing with the results returned? Is there an image in some of the fields?

Comment: No image is stored in DB. There is no other essential code involved.
In the windows form, one text field(textBox1), one button(button1) and one datagrid(dataGridView1) is used. 
When the application runs, I manually enter query in textbox1 (say select * from table1) and hit button1 and this button1_click() method fires and populates datagridview . 
Some of the cells in table1 contains NULL and it show the error (as in the image). I tried all the mentioned "TRIED SOLUTIONS" but nothing helps to overcome/throw this error.
You could just try these in your IDE and face the same problem.

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible, maybe you should post something else so that we can reproduce the error you get like `table1` schema and some fictional data. Currently this code works fine for me!

Comment: @S.Akbari - I tried with my home system with different version. It works fine. Thanks. 
In my first trial with VS2010 in office, when I queried a table with multiple columns(15+) I got to move the horizontal scrollbar in datagridview and at that time I got this error.

Answer (score 1):

Try in a different system. This works perfect for me.

Also clean and rebuild your solution and restart your IDE. Or try clearing your system's cache, temp files.

`IDE`: Visual Studio 2013

`.Net` : 4.0